# Constant definition in multiple files

Tags: c++, constants

I am reading "C++ primer plus". In Chapter 9, it talks about the difference between C++ and C when dealing with const modifier:

"In C++ (but not C), the const modifier alters the default storage classes slightly. Whereas a global variable has external linkage by default, a const global variable has internal linkage by default.

...

If global const declaration had external linkage as regular variable do, this would be an error because you can define a global variable in one file only. That is, only one file can contain the proceding declaration, and the other files have to provide reference declarations using the extern keywords."

I tried to test this claim with the following program:

file.h:

```
using namespace std;

const char *constant = "Magic";
```

file1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "file.h"
extern void file2();
int main(){
  cout << "constant = " << constant << endl;
  file2();
}
```

file2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "file.h"

void file2(){
  cout << "file2 constant = " << constant << endl;
}
```

Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -g
INCLUDE = file.h
src = file2.cpp file1.cpp

all: $(src) $(INCLUDE)
  g++ $(CFLAGS) -o file $(src)

clean:
  rm -f file
```

When I do make, i get the following error message:

```
g++ -Wall -g -o file file2.cpp file1.cpp
/tmp/ccdl16Tw.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `constant'
/tmp/ccA3ZEHa.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

gcc version 4.8.2

UPDATE:

If I do

```
 char* const constant = "Magic";
```

Then make will give me this warning:

g++ -Wall -g -o file file2.cpp file1.cpp

```
In file included from file2.cpp:2:0:
file.h:3:24: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
 char* const constant = "Magic";
                        ^
In file included from file1.cpp:2:0:
file.h:3:24: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
 char* const constant = "Magic";
```

Comment: Did you try `extern const char *constant;` in the header, and e.g `const char *constant = "Magic";` in one of the translation units? Globals are still different when used outside `class`/`struct` declaratons.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think he means that the `const` should have internal linkage, so the linker should not complain about duplicate symbols.

Comment: @vsoftco _"I think he means that the `const` should have internal linkage"_, which is obviously wrong, unless specified along a `struct` or `class` also `static` has it's meanings in c++, that differ from c.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I agree with vsoftco. This is my understanding from the text in the book. BTW, I forgot to call file2 in my main(), updated.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no, I don't think it's wrong. `const` seems to have internal linkage by default (no need for `static`), I don't have the standard in front of me, but I tried OP's program with a `const constant = 10;` and the linker doesn't complain about duplicates anymore. The problem here is that the pointer is not `const`, as pointed by @user2079303 answer

Comment: @vsoftco OK, that might well explain it (mentioning `static` was sideways). I also don't have the standard at hand, or proved against it.

Comment: @vsoftco, what is 3.5/(3.2)? could you send the link?

Comment: @dannycrane It is the relevant section of the C++ standard, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf

Comment: @vsoftco, appreciate it!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`const char *constant` is not `const`. It is a non-`const` pointer to `const char`. Being non-`const` variable in namespace scope, it has external linkage by default and thus you get multiple definition error.

`const char * const constant` is `const` and would behave as you are expecting.

Update:

`char* const constant` on the other hand would be a `const` pointer to `char`. Being `const` it does have internal linkage by default in namespace scope.

However, you shouldn't initialize it with a string literal (as the compiler warning points out) because that's not allowed by the standard (such conversion is illegal in c++11 and was deprecated before that). String literals are allowed to be stored in read only memory and you aren't allowed to modify them runtime. That is why pointing to a string literal with a pointer to non-`const char` is dangerous.

Comment: Also, It's worth noting that `const` qualifies whatever is on its *left*, except when used as the first qualifier, so the original definition is the same as `char const * constant` - the `char` is `const`, but not the pointer.

Comment: in const char* const constant, the first const tells that the char pointed by the pointer is constant, and the second const tells that the pointer is pointing at constant address, correct? What does it mean if I have char* const constant = "Magic"? I have updated the behavior I get from my program. I will take your answer, but if you can answer this one extra question, that is really helpful!

Comment: `char* const constant = "Magic"` means the pointer is `const` (i.e., you cannot reassign the pointer to another C-style string/string literal) and points to `char`. Furthermore, C++ deprecates using a pointer-to-char to point to a string literal, it has to be a pointer to `const char`. In other words, `char* const constant = "Magic"` produces `warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'`.

Comment: @vsoftco, that explains a lot! Just a note: my compiler gives a warning instead of an error when I use char* const constant = "Magic". but i agree it is not a good programming practice

Comment: @dannycrane yes, indeed, edited my comment after I realized it also.

Comment: I still have one more confusion. `char* const constant = "Magic"` means the pointer is always a char pointer. `const char* constant = "Magic" ` means the pointer is pointing a constant char "Magic". Now when I combine these two: `const char* const constant = "Magic"`, means I have a pointer which is always a char pointer, pointing to a constant string "Magic". Logically, the combination of these two logical statement does not prevent from me reassigning it to another constant char "MAGIC". Or this is simply a C++ definition thing...

Comment: Does `const char* constant = "Magic"` mean the memory location pointing by constant will never change and when we dereference constant, it will also be used as a char pointer?

Comment: "Does ... mean the memory location pointing by constant will never change". Yes, the value of a pointer is the address of the pointed object. `const` variable never changes. Therefore, the quoted statement is correct.

Comment: "it will also be used as a char pointer". `const` does not mean that, but since it *is* a pointer to `char`, one might expect you to use it as such.